# Restrict certain elements in a page to logged in users

Tags: php

I'm following this tutorial (https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php) for creating a logging system in PHP and MySQL. To restrict the access to certain pages for logged in users only we use this code:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<p>this page is for logged in users only</p>
```

Anyway, there is a page to view the profile of a user and it should be accessible for logged in or non logged in users, but some aspects of the program should be only available for logged in users, like viewing, say, the bell of the notifications.
For now I've been using this way;

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== false){
  // user is logged in so display notifications bell
}
?>
```

This approach works but it doesn't seem very efficient. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a True/False value I would suggest using something like $_SESSION['username'],

Eg:

```
<?php
//include any header / common files.

// Start Session 
sessoin_start();

//Add function here to check session has not expired

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   // Do Redirect, then return so no other code is executed
   return;
}
 
// Render Page for logged in user.
```